# Apply comparison operations defined in dataset

Tags: pyspark

I have a table with several fields on which I need to do data quality checks.

The data quality checks are defined as rules in a second table.

**Data Table:**

| ID | Name1 | Name2 | Zip1 | Zip2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | John | John | 123 | 123 |
| 002 | Sara | Sarah | 234 | 234 |
| 003 | Bill | William | 999 | 111 |
| 004 | Lisa | Lisa | 888 | 333 |
| 005 | Martin | Martin | 345 | 345 |
| 006 | Margaret | Margaret | 456 | 456 |
| 007 | Oscar | Oscar | 678 | 678 |
| 008 | Peter | Peter | 789 | 789 |

**Rule Table:**

| ID | FieldLeft | FieldRight | ComparisonOperation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R001 | Name1 | Name2 | EQUALS |
| R002 | Zip1 | Zip2 | EQUALS |

So the rules essentially are saying: Name1=Name2 and Zip1=Zip2

The expected output is the records that are non-compliant with the rules.
It should produce one row per rule violation (see for record 003, both the name and the zip are inconsistent -> so two lines are in the result for record 003).

**Output:**

| Rule | ID | FieldLeft | FieldRight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R001 | 002 | Sara | Sarah |
| R001 | 003 | Bill | William |
| R002 | 003 | 999 | 111 |
| R002 | 004 | 888 | 333 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's my implementation

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("001", "John", "John", "123", "123"),
        ("002", "Sara", "Sarah", "234", "234"),
        ("003", "Bill", "William", "999", "111"),
        ("004", "Lisa", "Lisa", "888", "333"),
        ("005", "Martin", "Martin", "345", "345"),
        ("006", "Margaret", "Margaret", "456", "456"),
        ("007", "Oscar", "Oscar", "678", "678"),
        ("008", "Peter", "Peter", "789", "789"),
    ],
    ["ID", "Name1", "Name2", "Zip1", "Zip2"],
)
#df.show()

rule_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("R001", "Name1", "Name2", "EQUALS"),
        ("R002", "Zip1", "Zip2", "EQUALS"),
    ],
    ["ID", "FieldLeft", "FieldRight", "ComparisonOperation"],
)
#rule_df.show()

final_rule_df = (rule_df
    .withColumn(
        "operator",
        F.when(
            F.lower(F.col("ComparisonOperation")) == "equals",
            F.lit(" == "),
        )
        .when(
            F.lower(F.col("ComparisonOperation")) == "not equals",
            F.lit(" != "),
        )
        .when(
            F.lower(F.col("ComparisonOperation")) == "greater than",
            F.lit(" > "),
        )
        .when(
            F.lower(F.col("ComparisonOperation")) == "less than",
            F.lit(" < "),
        )
        .otherwise(F.lit("operator_na")),
    )
    .filter(F.col("operator") != "operator_na" )
    .withColumn("expression", concat(F.col("FieldLeft"),F.col("operator"), F.col("FieldRight"))  )
    .drop("operator")
    #.withColumn(
    #    "select_clause", 
    #    F.concat(
    #        F.lit('"'),
    #        F.lit( F.col("FieldLeft") ),
    #        F.lit(" as " + F.col("FieldLeft")._jc.toString()),
    #        F.lit('"'),
    #        F.lit(", "),
    #        F.lit('"'),
    #        F.col("FieldRight"),
    #        F.lit(" as " + F.col("FieldRight")._jc.toString()),
    #        F.lit('"'),
    #    )
    #)                      
)
final_rule_df.show(truncate=False)

schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("Rule", StringType(), True),
        StructField("ID", StringType(), True),
        StructField("FieldLeft", StringType(), True),
        StructField("FieldRight", StringType(), True),
    ]
)

final_non_compliant_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD(), schema
)

rule_df_rows = final_rule_df.select("*").collect()
for row in rule_df_rows:
    rule_id = row.ID
    print(f"rule_id: {rule_id}")
    
    expression = row.expression
    print(f"expression: {expression}")
    
    #select_clause = row.select_clause
    #print(f"select_clause: {select_clause}")
    
    rule_df = df.filter(expr(expression))
    #rule_df.show()
    
    non_compliant_df = (df.subtract(rule_df)
        .withColumn("Rule", F.lit(rule_id))
        .withColumn("FieldLeft", F.col(row.FieldLeft))
        .withColumn("FieldRight", F.col(row.FieldRight))
        .selectExpr("Rule", "ID", "FieldLeft", "FieldRight")
    )
    non_compliant_df.show()
    final_non_compliant_df = final_non_compliant_df.union(non_compliant_df)

final_non_compliant_df.show()
```

OUTPUTS:

```
+----+---------+----------+-------------------+--------------+
|ID  |FieldLeft|FieldRight|ComparisonOperation|expression    |
+----+---------+----------+-------------------+--------------+
|R001|Name1    |Name2     |EQUALS             |Name1 == Name2|
|R002|Zip1     |Zip2      |EQUALS             |Zip1 == Zip2  |
+----+---------+----------+-------------------+--------------+

rule_id: R001
expression: Name1 == Name2
+----+---+---------+----------+
|Rule| ID|FieldLeft|FieldRight|
+----+---+---------+----------+
|R001|003|     Bill|   William|
|R001|002|     Sara|     Sarah|
+----+---+---------+----------+

rule_id: R002
expression: Zip1 == Zip2
+----+---+---------+----------+
|Rule| ID|FieldLeft|FieldRight|
+----+---+---------+----------+
|R002|004|      888|       333|
|R002|003|      999|       111|
+----+---+---------+----------+
```

final output:

```
+----+---+---------+----------+
|Rule| ID|FieldLeft|FieldRight|
+----+---+---------+----------+
|R001|003|     Bill|   William|
|R001|002|     Sara|     Sarah|
|R002|004|      888|       333|
|R002|003|      999|       111|
+----+---+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much! One question: is there a way to parallelize the for-loop going over the rules? In my scenario I am looking at hundreds of rules going over datasets in the millions of rows. So I wonder if that could be optimized.

Comment: Thanks for the other answer! I ended up sticking to the above solution.
I was able to optimize it by using the NOT operator ~ like so: `non_compliant_df = df.filter(~expr(expression))`
That way I don't need to do the additional step with the subtract operation.

Comment: i've been thinking about this more..and you should be able to use a dynamic sql string to generate all the logic at once for each rule. then you can run that single sql against each dataframe that you create a view for using `df.createOrReplaceTempView("v_df")` ..i'll revisit this

Comment: That would be great!

Comment: @hbit i added the other possible solution

Answer (score 0):

@hbit
I'm not sure about the complete solution for doing this without an explicit loop. I got as far as using a cross join to add a rule for every record which creates a cartesian result set. you can see the records that eval to false you should be able to pull out all the correct false records based on the rule columns

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("001", "John", "John", "123", "123"),
        ("002", "Sara", "Sarah", "234", "234"),
        ("003", "Bill", "William", "999", "111"),
        ("004", "Lisa", "Lisa", "888", "333"),
        ("005", "Martin", "Martin", "345", "345"),
        ("006", "Margaret", "Margaret", "456", "456"),
        ("007", "Oscar", "Oscar", "678", "678"),
        ("008", "Peter", "Peter", "789", "789"),
    ],
    ["ID", "Name1", "Name2", "Zip1", "Zip2"],
)


rule_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("R001", "Name1", "Name2", "EQUALS"),
        ("R002", "Zip1", "Zip2", "EQUALS"),
    ],
    ["ID", "FieldLeft", "FieldRight", "ComparisonOperation"],
)
#rule_df.show()

main_df_name = "df."
df_cols = [f"{main_df_name}{x}" for x in df.columns]  
#print(df_cols)
f_rule_df = (rule_df
    .withColumn(
        "operator",
        F.when(
            F.lower(F.col("ComparisonOperation")) == "equals",
            F.lit(" == "),
        )
        .when(
            F.lower(F.col("ComparisonOperation")) == "not equals",
            F.lit(" != "),
        )
        .when(
            F.lower(F.col("ComparisonOperation")) == "greater than",
            F.lit(" > "),
        )
        .when(
            F.lower(F.col("ComparisonOperation")) == "less than",
            F.lit(" < "),
        )
        .otherwise(F.lit("operator_na")),
    )
    .filter(F.col("operator") != "operator_na" )
    .withColumn("FieldLeft", concat(F.lit(main_df_name),F.col("FieldLeft") ) )
    .withColumn("FieldRight", concat(F.lit(main_df_name),F.col("FieldRight") ) )
    .withColumn("expression", concat(F.lit("("), F.col("FieldLeft"),F.col("operator"), F.col("FieldRight"), F.lit(").alias('" ), F.col("ID"),F.lit("')")   )  )
    .drop("operator")        
)
f_rule_df.show(truncate=False)
f_rule_df_name = "final_rule_df."
f_rule_df_cols = [f"{f_rule_df_name}{x}" for x in f_rule_df.columns]  
#print(f_rule_df_cols)

expressions = final_rule_df.select("expression").distinct().collect()

exp_array = [str(x.expression) for x in expressions]
#print(exp_array)

exp_array_cols = df_cols + f_rule_df_cols + exp_array

final_df = (
    df.crossJoin(final_rule_df)
    .select([eval(x) for x in exp_array_cols])
    .drop("ComparisonOperation")
    .drop("expression")
)

final_df.show()

+----+---------+----------+-------------------+------------------------------------+
|ID  |FieldLeft|FieldRight|ComparisonOperation|expression                          |
+----+---------+----------+-------------------+------------------------------------+
|R001|df.Name1 |df.Name2  |EQUALS             |(df.Name1 == df.Name2).alias('R001')|
|R002|df.Zip1  |df.Zip2   |EQUALS             |(df.Zip1 == df.Zip2).alias('R002')  |
+----+---------+----------+-------------------+------------------------------------+

+---+--------+--------+----+----+----+---------+----------+-----+-----+
| ID|   Name1|   Name2|Zip1|Zip2|  ID|FieldLeft|FieldRight| R001| R002|
+---+--------+--------+----+----+----+---------+----------+-----+-----+
|001|    John|    John| 123| 123|R001| df.Name1|  df.Name2| true| true|
|001|    John|    John| 123| 123|R002|  df.Zip1|   df.Zip2| true| true|
|002|    Sara|   Sarah| 234| 234|R001| df.Name1|  df.Name2|false| true|
|002|    Sara|   Sarah| 234| 234|R002|  df.Zip1|   df.Zip2|false| true|
|003|    Bill| William| 999| 111|R001| df.Name1|  df.Name2|false|false|
|003|    Bill| William| 999| 111|R002|  df.Zip1|   df.Zip2|false|false|
|004|    Lisa|    Lisa| 888| 333|R001| df.Name1|  df.Name2| true|false|
|004|    Lisa|    Lisa| 888| 333|R002|  df.Zip1|   df.Zip2| true|false|
|005|  Martin|  Martin| 345| 345|R001| df.Name1|  df.Name2| true| true|
|005|  Martin|  Martin| 345| 345|R002|  df.Zip1|   df.Zip2| true| true|
|006|Margaret|Margaret| 456| 456|R001| df.Name1|  df.Name2| true| true|
|006|Margaret|Margaret| 456| 456|R002|  df.Zip1|   df.Zip2| true| true|
|007|   Oscar|   Oscar| 678| 678|R001| df.Name1|  df.Name2| true| true|
|007|   Oscar|   Oscar| 678| 678|R002|  df.Zip1|   df.Zip2| true| true|
|008|   Peter|   Peter| 789| 789|R001| df.Name1|  df.Name2| true| true|
|008|   Peter|   Peter| 789| 789|R002|  df.Zip1|   df.Zip2| true| true|
+---+--------+--------+----+----+----+---------+----------+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 3rd implementation attempt. this one is using dynamic sql and only loops through all the rules to create the appropriate sql case string and then applies it all at once to the main dataset.
only caveat is how to show the same record failing twice with this method. I'm sure there's a way

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("001", "John", "John", "123", "123"),
        ("002", "Sara", "Sarah", "234", "234"),
        ("003", "Bill", "William", "999", "111"),
        ("004", "Lisa", "Lisa", "888", "333"),
        ("005", "Martin", "Martin", "345", "345"),
        ("006", "Margaret", "Margaret", "456", "456"),
        ("007", "Oscar", "Oscar", "678", "678"),
        ("008", "Peter", "Peter", "789", "789"),
    ],
    ["ID", "Name1", "Name2", "Zip1", "Zip2"],
)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("v_df")



rule_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("R001", "Name1", "Name2", "EQUALS"),
        ("R002", "Zip1", "Zip2", "EQUALS"),
    ],
    ["rule_id", "FieldLeft", "FieldRight", "ComparisonOperation"],
)
rule_df.show()

f_rule_df = (rule_df
    .withColumn(
        "operator",
        F.when(
            F.lower(F.col("ComparisonOperation")) == "equals",
            F.lit(" == "),
        )
        .when(
            F.lower(F.col("ComparisonOperation")) == "not equals",
            F.lit(" != "),
        )
        .when(
            F.lower(F.col("ComparisonOperation")) == "greater than",
            F.lit(" > "),
        )
        .when(
            F.lower(F.col("ComparisonOperation")) == "less than",
            F.lit(" < "),
        )
        .otherwise(F.lit("operator_na")),
    )
    .filter(F.col("operator") != "operator_na" )
    .withColumn("expression", concat(F.lit("("), F.col("FieldLeft"),F.col("operator"), F.col("FieldRight"), F.lit(")")   )  )
    .drop("operator")        
)
f_rule_df.show()

rule_df_rows = f_rule_df.select("*").collect()

rule_array = []
rule_array.append("case \n")

pass_array = []
pass_array.append("case \n")

field_left_array = []
field_left_array.append("case \n")

field_right_array = []
field_right_array.append("case \n")

for row in rule_df_rows:
    rule_id = row.rule_id
    print(f"rule_id: {rule_id}")
    
    expression = row.expression
    print(f"expression: {expression}")
    
    field_left = row.FieldLeft
    print(f"field_left: {field_left}")
    
    field_right = row.FieldRight
    print(f"field_right: {field_right}")
    
    rule_str = f"\t when {expression} = false then '{rule_id}' \n"
    rule_array.append(rule_str)
    
    pass_str = f"\t when {expression} = false then false \n"
    pass_array.append(pass_str)
    
    field_left_str = f"\t when {expression} = false then {field_left} \n"
    field_left_array.append(field_left_str)

    field_right_str = f"\t when {expression} = false then {field_right} \n"
    field_right_array.append(field_right_str)
    
rule_array.append("""\t else 'NA' \nend as rule_id""")
f_rule_str = "".join(rule_array)
#print(f_rule_str)
    
pass_array.append("""\t else true \nend as pass_flag""")
f_pass_str = "".join(pass_array)
#print(f_pass_str)

field_left_array.append("""\t else 'NA' \nend as FieldLeft""")
f_field_left_str = "".join(field_left_array)
#print(f_field_left_str)

field_right_array.append("""\t else 'NA' \nend as FieldRight""")
f_field_right_str = "".join(field_right_array)
#print(f_field_right_str)

f_case_str = ",\n".join([f_rule_str,f_pass_str,f_field_left_str,f_field_right_str ])
print(f_case_str)

f_df = spark.sql(
f"""
    select 
            *,
            {f_case_str}
    from v_df      
"""
)
f_df = (f_df
    .filter(F.col("pass_flag") == False)
    .select("rule_id", "ID", "FieldLeft", "FieldRight")
)
f_df.show()

+-------+---+---------+----------+
|rule_id| ID|FieldLeft|FieldRight|
+-------+---+---------+----------+
|   R001|002|     Sara|     Sarah|
|   R001|003|     Bill|   William|
|   R002|004|      888|       333|
+-------+---+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks. Having one row per rule violation is a key requirement for me, though.
But please you have helped me enough - I am using your original answer (in the modified version with the small optimizations I described in the comments)